# The list source for ng-repeat called too many times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
angular.module('NGTest', [
])
.controller('ItemList', ['$scope', function($scope) {
 console.log("ItemList controller init");
 var self = this;
  self.count = 4;
  self.getItems = function() {
   console.log("ItemList.getItems() called");
   return [];
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="NGTest">
<div ng-controller="ItemList as lst">
<select ng-options="value for value in [1,2,3,4,5]" ng-model="lst.count"></select>
<div ng-repeat="item in lst.getItems()">foo </div>
</div>
</div>
```

By log entries, you can see that at startup, the lst.getItems() function is called twice. Why twice?

It is also called when you change the value of lst.count, that is not used at all.
Ok, I understand that AngularJS can not be that smart and see that the code of lst.getItems() does not depend on lst.count, but I'd expect that by default it assumes it does not and I have to feed it in function parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why twice

You will need to read up on how angular digest cycles work. Each cycle will run a minimum of 2 digests and more if scope changes within those digests.

Using a function as source in view for ng-repeat is not a good idea. Get your data in controller and pass to view as scope array

```
self.items= getItems();   

function getItems(){
   console.log("ItemList.getItems() called");
   return [];
}
```

Now the function will only be called once...when controller initializes

View

```
<div ng-repeat="item in lst.items">{{item}}</div>
```

Comment: I my real application, the reason this function is there in ng-repeat source is that this list depends on the values of form controls under the same controller.

Comment: Use `filter` in ng-repeat and create custom filter if needed

Comment: That's not so easy, the list is retrieved via http from the database. Keeping the full list on the client side is not an option.

Comment: Ok, I removed the function call, and left the source as simple property of controller. I now update this property via help of ng-change directives in the filter criteria form controls.

Comment: sounds like much better set up